# Pure Javascript based jabber client

Tags: javascript, xmpp, strophe

We are developing an `HTML5` chat client using `strophe.js` along with `flxhr.js` & `strophe.flxhr.js`. The later js file injects a swf file in the DOM at runtime. Its through this flash it tries to overcome JavaScript’s same origin policy issue.

We also intend to access this chat client via touch devices, iOS & Android & desktops as well. Its clear the modern devices won't have flash available & if the desktop browsers have disable the flash player, then this approach won't work.

Could any one suggest an alternative approach to develop a pure JavaScript Jabber client or is there any another way to achieve this using strophe.js or its variant. Any help would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no jabber expert, but a few minutes of Googling led me to a list of XMPP clients. I'd suggest using or starting with one of these: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/

Note: There are several web-based clients on the list, such as: http://candy-chat.github.com/candy/

Answer (score 1):

I use Apache with mod_proxy in most of my installations to overcome the XHR restrictions.
The Candy developers have good configuration examples here: http://candy-chat.github.com/candy/

Most other webservers also have proxy modules if you don't run Apache on your site.

Answer (score 0):

You open to options other than XMPP?

We've been playing with www.pubnub.com ourselves for something similar. It's not free, but would give you a pure-javascript that works on desktop and mobile.

http://blog.pubnub.com/build-real-time-chat-10-lines-code/ might be of particular interest, or http://blog.pubnub.com/html5-websockets-beautiful-real-time-chat-on-mobile-using-pubnubs-channel-presence/ for another example.

Answer (score 0):

flXHR and other flash offerings for cross-browser ajax can work fine and still have a role to play for 3rd party servers that are not under your control.

However, in this case it sounds like the server is under your control, so you can now adopt a "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing" (CORS) approach.

I'll not try to describe CORS, but here's a link :

https://www.bionicspirit.com/blog/2011/03/24/cross-domain-requests.html

Much on CORS is available on the web. The article above is a particularly good place for you to start because it specifically discusses CORS as an alternative to flXHR.